# How to achieve a certain url format using @RequestMapping in SpringMVC

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, url-pattern

I am trying to create a simple application using SpringMVC for learning purpose. I want to have the urls for various actions in this format

```
http://localhost:8080/appname/controllername/actionname.html
```

The url-pattern specified inside the servlet-mapping for the DispatcherServlet is

```
<url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
```

here is one of my methods in the ContactController

```
@RequestMapping("list.html")
public ModelAndView showContacts() {        
    ModelAndView modelandview = new ModelAndView("list"); 

    modelandview.addObject("message","Your contact book");

    return modelandview;
}
```

Now everything works fine when i navigate to,

```
http://localhost:8080/appname/list.html
```

However I want the url to be,

```
http://localhost:8080/appname/contact/list.html
```

I tried using `@RequestMapping("/contact/list.html")` on top of the method but it doesnt help (shows 404 error with description The requested resource () is not available) .

How can this be done ?

Also, is it possible to have multiple url-patterns for servlet mapping for eg. `*.html or *.do` ?

PS. i am using apache-tomcat on Ubuntu desktop

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
@RequestMapping("/contact")
public class ContactController
{
  @RequestMapping("/list.html")
  public ModelAndView showContacts()
  {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Also, `@RequestMapping` accepts an array of strings to allow multiple mappings.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
@RequestMapping("/controllername")
```

before class Declaration.

Answer (score 0):

BTW, you may simplify even more!

```
This is easily remedied by using an XML-configured strategy for matching URI paths to controller classes and @RequestMapping annotations for method-level mapping only.
```

For details, see chapter `Removing Class-Level Request Mappings` at http://www.infoq.com/articles/spring-2.5-ii-spring-mvc